# Config PhpStorm 2021 switch case style

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm

PhpStorm 2021 formatting my switch case as follows:

```
switch ($_GET["x"] ?? 1) {
    case 1:
        {
            $z = 1;
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        {
            $z = 2;
        }
        break;
}
```

But I would like it to be formatted braces on end the line like:

```
switch ($_GET["x"] ?? 1) {
    case 1:{
        $z = 1;
    }
        break;
    case 2:{
        $z = 2;
    }
        break;
}
```

My old config (by PhpStorm 2017) doesn't work, code style like in second code-block

How to turn back non new-line code-style?

Comment: Why do you want `{}` in the case? They are not required

Comment: There's no config options for braces in `case` in IDE.

Comment: ty for clarification